# MSSQL retrieve todays date (subtract a month) and convert into a timestamp

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp

What i was struggling with: (getting current dates epoch and subtracting a specific time for a time range)

> and MotherObservations.Timestamp > '1444521913713'

Answer:

> and MotherObservations.Timestamp/1000 > datediff(ss, '19700101', dateadd(month, -2, getdate()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp in SQL Server is a synonym for rowversion. As such it is an automatically generated, unique binary number and not a datatype that holds a date and time. Thus you cannot convert a datetime to a timestamp or vice-versa.

Comment: The timestamp i have within the database is an epoch timestamp i think, therefore the timestamp i already have is a representation of time, i wish to get a timestamp for todays date so i can merely subtract a months worth.

Comment: OK, if it's an epoch timestamp then to get today's date, subtract a month and convert it to an epoch you need select datediff(ss, '19700101', dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))